# "Membership **to** physics-related entities"?

Tags: prepositions, expressions, prepositional-phrases

This is a question that cropped-up while John Doe was preparing the English version of his CV. He wanted to include a section wherein he was to list some of the physics societies to which he belongs. He decided to title the section something like

**Membership to physics-related entities**

The question is this: does the phrase "membership to" sound awkward to you? If so, what would you have written therein instead? Membership of physics-related entities?

Comment: Even "entities" sounds unnatural.  "Societies" or "organizations" would both be preferred.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - I had the same thought! I was hoping that was just a placeholder for what would actually be put in the CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice? Don't use *membership*, use *member*:

> Member of physics-related entities

If you must use *membership*, I would use the preposition *in*:

> Membership **in** physics-related entities